# Type object is not subscriptable while writing algorithm in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert my algorithm into python code. The algorithm is as follows:

```
For i = 1 To n
                For j = 1 To (m - 1)
                    del1 = C(i - 1, j) - C(i - 1, j - 1)
                    del2 = C(i - 1, j + 1) - C(i - 1, j)
                    If del2 = 0 Then
                        r = 0
                    Else
                        r = del1 / del2
                    End If
Next i
```

I tried to convert the above chunk of code step by stop. For del1 I tried to write the python code as follows:

```
del1 = [[C[i-1,j]-C[i-1,j-1] for j in range(1,(m-1))]for i in range [0,int(n)]]
```

I get the error TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable. Can anyone give me starting point on how to convert the above algorithm into python code ?

**Edit:**

```
C = [[0 for j in range(0,int(m))]for i in range(0)]
C = [[1 for i in range(0,int(n))]for j in range(0)]
```

Thanks.

Jdbaba

Comment: What is `C`?  Where is it created?

Comment: that results in `C` being an empty list as `range(0) == []`, so the inner list comprehension never evaluates.

Comment: C is _still_ an empty list and the second assignment overrides the first.

Comment: Actually I wrote those two lines of code to interpret the following algorithm.  `For j = 0 To m
                C(0, j) = 0
            Next

          
            For i = 0 To n
                C(i, 0) = 1.0#
            Next i `

Comment: That is not what your python code does.  Add `print(C)` lines to your code.

Comment: and any line of code more than 15 characters should not be put into the comments, it is impossible to read.

Comment: try `C = [[0 if i != 0 else 1 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]`

Comment: I used the following code to fix that problem of empty list. Now, it prints values. `C = [[0 for j in range(0,int(m))]for i in range(0,int(n))]`  
`C = [[1 for i in range(0,int(n))]for j in range(0,int(m))]    `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should be:

```
del1 = [[C[i-1,j]-C[i-1,j-1] for j in range(1,(m-1))]for i in range(0,int(n))]
```

`[]` -> `()` on the last `range`

The above notation will work if `C` is something like a `numpy` array that supports multi-dimensional slicing.  If `C` is a list of lists, the following should work:

```
del1 = [[C[i-1][j]-C[i-1][j-1] for j in range(1,(m-1))]for i in range(0,int(n))]
```

Comment: C = [[0 for j in range(0,int(m))]for i in range(0)]
C = [[0 for i in range(0,int(m))]for j in range(0)]

Comment: @Jdbaba You should add that detail to your question.

Comment: I used your first solution and added int(). The code is `del1 = [[C[i-1,j]-C[i-1,j-1] for j in range(1,int(m-1))]for i in range (0,int(n))]` . But it gives the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`.

Comment: @Jdbaba That is because lists only support indexing in one dimension, and you need to use the second solution if you use a list of lists.

Comment: When I use the second solution then I get the error "IndexError: list index out of range". How can I fix this ?

Comment: because your `C` is an empty list

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `range(0,int(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, anything inside [] ie, square-brackets is called subscriptable -- it represents an array concept.

But, in loops we might use range, where we can have a typo of [] instead of () paranthesis.

The range value is not in a subscript format or separable elements of array.

So, the only solution is to change [] to () and run..